# float number in button size in tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

When the following code is executed, it gives an error that float numbers are not acceptable. So how do you adjust the height and width with float numbers?

```
win = Tk()
btn = Button(win, width = 3.5 , height = 4.5)
btn.grid()
win.mainloop()
```

Comment: Integers, like `Button(win, width = 30 , height = 40)`. Check the documentation [here](https://tk-tutorial.readthedocs.io/en/latest/button/button.html)

Comment: but i want to use float numbers. can't i?

Comment: You can't because those are sizes in pixels.

Comment: @deponovo they are not pixels tho, they are characters of the font, if You want them to be pixels You have to create a pixel for example `pixel = PhotoImage(width=1, height=1)` and then set that as the `image=pixel` for the button then tho You won't be able to put text there or sth

Comment: @deponovo and btw there shouldn't be space around `=` here: `Button(win, width = 30 , height = 40)` it should be like this: `Button(win, width=30 , height=40)` as per `PEP 8: E251 unexpected spaces around keyword / parameter equals`

Comment: @Matiiss Firstly, you are not creating pixels, instead you are creating an image, and using an image forces the button to use pixels as unit for measurement. Secondly, _"btw there shouldn't be space around..."_: PEP8 is a convention, whether  to follow or not is upto us. Following is recommended but not mandatory, so saying "shouldn't" is incorrect and misleading there.

Comment: Why exactly do you want to be able to use floats for width and height?

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if you want to specify the size of the button in pixels, or specifically in a rational amount of characters, but in the first case skip to the second part of the answer.

In both cases you will have to set the size in pixels, if you want to specify it in a rational amount of characters, you will first have to get the size of these characters:

```
import tkinter as tk
import tkinter.font as font

win = tk.Tk()
defaultfont = font.nametofont("TkDefaultFont")
width = defaultfont.measure("k") # has character length, not sure if this works on any platform
height = defaultfont.metrics()['linespace']

w = int(3.5*width)
h = int(4.5*height)
```

Then you have to set the button size in pixels, you have 2 possibilities:

1. Set a button image, and specify the size in pixels (like [Matiiss](https://stackoverflow.com/users/14531062/matiiss) proposed)
2. Put a frame with a specific size and make the button span the frame

Like this:

```
pixelVirtual = tk.PhotoImage(width=1, height=1)
btn = tk.Button(win, text='kkkk', image=pixelVirtual, width=w , height=h, compound="c")
btn.grid(row=0, column=1)

fr = tk.Frame(win, width=w, height=h, borderwidth=0, highlightthickness=0 )
fr.propagate(False)
fr.grid(row=1, column=1, sticky="nsew")
btn2 = tk.Button(fr, text='kkkk')
btn2.pack(expand=True, fill="both")
```

The result will not be entirely the same as there is some padding when using character sizes with the button (you can see this by making a button of integer sizes with this method compared to making the button with integer sizes in the default character based method.)